# I want a script to insert a student ID number in cell B5, and then download & export the sheet as a PDF, naming the file with the student's ID

Tags: pdf, google-sheets, download, rename

I have a Student Progress Report in Google Sheets that populates data (using queries, filters, vlookups, sparklines, etc.) based on a unique student ID that is entered in cell B5. This works great for me as a teacher to show to student individually on the screen. However, my school wants to use the report to communicate to all students and parents.

This would pretty much be logistically impossible for a thousand students. Is there a way to write a script that would automatically enter a student ID in B5, download it as a PDF and name the file with the student ID number? And then repeat the process for the next student ID?

I've been working so hard to make this work and am hitting a brick wall now in terms of how to share this information with students and parents (while protecting privacy, etc. of whole-school data that is found in hidden sheets). I know my way around formulas, even more "advanced" ones, but writing scripts is not something I can do yet. If I can find one that is close to what I want to accomplish, I know enough to make small customizations, but I'm really lost on this one. I'd be so appreciative if anyone had any ideas or could help me!

Comment: To use the script below, you will need to provide additional information: names of the sheets (student list and report), id of the archive where the pdf files will be stored, range where we can find the ids. Perhaps you could share an excerpt from your project that shows this information.

Comment: The process could be long (I don't know how many students), so it will be necessary to mark each id as soon as the pdf is created to be able to continue the script when you have reached the maximum time allowed by google....

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you read the description of the tags you added? Specifically, [tag:script] says _"DON'T USE THIS TAG! Every SO question is about scripts one way or another. Use appropriate tags like [tag:bash], [tag:javascript], [tag:google-apps-script] or [tag:python] instead."_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a draft

```
function saveAllAsPDF(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sh1 = ss.getSheetByName('IMPORT Masterlist');       
  const sh2 = ss.getSheetByName('Student Progress Report');            
  sh1.getRange('A2:A'+sh1.getLastRow()).getValues().flat().forEach(id => {
    if (id != '') {
      sh2.getRange('B5').setValue(id)
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      savePDF()
    }
  })
}

function savePDF(){
  const folderID = '1N0AIh5oEszYw_NXKD0Vx1XrXUiPuUadR';
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Student Progress Report');      
  const d = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyy-MM-dd")
  const filename = sh.getRange('B5').getValue() + '_' + d + ".pdf"
  const url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + ss.getId() + '/export?';
  const exportOptions =
    'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' + 
    '&size=A4' + 
    '&portrait=true' +                     
    '&fitw=true' +                        
    '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' + 
    '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false' + 
    '&fzr=false' +
    '&gid=' + sh.getSheetId();
  var params = {method:"GET",headers:{"authorization":"Bearer "+ ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + exportOptions, params).getBlob();
  DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID).createFile(response.setName(filename));
}
```

Comment: Wow, I can't thank you enough for responding to my request!

Comment: Wow, I can't thank you enough for responding to my request! My report sheet is called "Student Progress Report." It pulls information from "IMPORT Masterlist!A1:1830" with the student ID being in Column A. It also pulls from "IMPORT PinkSheets!1-1000" with the student ID in Column A. And the 3rd place is pulls from is a sheet called "Progress Summary" A2:I. The folder where I could save the documents could be this--is that what you mean? (1N0AIh5oEszYw_NXKD0Vx1XrXUiPuUadR) You mentioned sharing an excerpt, but I'm not sure how to do that???

Comment: You mean you have 1830 students? I don't think you will be able to do all at once.

Comment: Try to run first only savePDF() function with one student and tell me if everything is ok. I have updated the answer with the given information.

Comment: Here's what is in the execution log after running the savePDF function:10:14:44 AM Notice Execution started
10:14:45 AM Error 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null
savePDF @ savePDF.gs:6

Comment: do you really have a dot at the end of the sheet name `Student Progress Report.` as you told me?

Comment: No dot at the end--so that was it I removed it from the script and it worked. I'm dancing with excitement! Thank you so very much!

Comment: I'm getting these errors. Also, should the 2 functions be saved separately or all in 1 script? I'm not sure if I'm even asking that question correctly. 1:05:00 PM Error 
Exception: Request failed for https://docs.google.com returned code 429. Truncated server response: <!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta name="description" content="Web word processing, presentations and spreadsheets"><meta name="viewport" c... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)
savePDF @ PDF.gs:31
(anonymous) @ PDF.gs:9
saveAllAsPDF @ PDF.gs:5

Comment: Do you remove the dot at the end twice? Is it possible for you to share your spreadsheet? You can gather the 2 function, but I prefer to test first savePDF. The other function will make a loop and call for it.

Comment: I'd like to offer my apologies. I had no idea that what I asked was not appropriate. I can assure you that I've not been lazy, though it would appear to you from not being able to show the effort of an example. I've poured countless hours into my project. I'm (clearly) not in the world of coding but am trying to learn. I only know of this website before when in search of ideas and solutions to problems I've had with formulas and the tiniest bit of coding I've tried. I won't do it again--still, thank you to the person who helped me. What you did is going to help a ton of students and families.